# c# Color Conversion CMYK to Cielab or RGB to Cielab using ICC Profile

Tags: c#, colors, rgb, cmyk, color-profile

I want to use the .icc Profile "ISOnewspaper26v4.icc" in C# !
But I have a problem now.. I don't know how to convert CMYK colors to Lab values or RGB to Lab values by using this ICC Profile ??!! How I can assign the profile??

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, C# and the associated libraries don't contain any functions for converting CMYK or RGB to Lab. The contain functions for converting CMYK to RGB (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412368/413337)).

The Windows API seems to have functions for converting between different color systems. It at least works for converting RGB to CMYK (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5251318/413337)).

You probably need to following extensions:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LabCOLOR
    {
        public ushort L;
        public ushort a;
        public ushort b;
        public ushort pad;
    };

    [DllImport("mscms.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    static extern bool TranslateColors(
        IntPtr hColorTransform,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2), In] RGBColor[] inputColors,
        uint nColors,
        ColorType ctInput,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2), Out] LABColor[] outputColors,
        ColorType ctOutput);
```

Then you should be able to replace "cmyk" with "lab" to convert from RGB to Lab colors. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Du you know, whether I can import a specific ICC Profile in "mscms" to convert this colors. I know that it is possible in LittleCMS but I have never never worked with pInfoke references.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to "convert" to CIE Lab with the help of a Lab space ICC profile. AGFA used to have one. Otherwise, one would have to write a routine to manually make the conversion, outside of ICM, through the A2B0 tag, for an output profile. Beware, that ISOnewspaperv4 profile is finacky.